# How do I insert values into a Map<K, V>?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a map of strings to strings. Below is what I've tried but neither method works. What's wrong with it?

```
public class Data
{
    private final Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    data["John"] = "Taxi Driver";
    data.put("John", "Taxi Driver");
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There are two issues here.

Firstly, you can't use the `[]` syntax like you may be able to in other languages. Square brackets only apply to arrays in Java, and so can only be used with integer indexes.

`data.put` is correct but that is a statement and so must exist in a method block. Only field declarations can exist at the class level. Here is an example where everything is within the local scope of a method:

```
public class Data {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
         data.put("John", "Taxi Driver");
         data.put("Mark", "Professional Killer");
     }
 }
```

If you want to initialize a map as a static field of a class then you can use [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V)), since Java 9:

```
public class Data {
    private static final Map<String, String> DATA = Map.of("John", "Taxi Driver");
}
```

Before Java 9, you can use a static initializer block to accomplish the same thing:

```
public class Data {
    private static final Map<String, String> DATA = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        DATA.put("John", "Taxi Driver");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is

```
data.put("John","Taxi driver");
```

Answer (score 3):

The two errors you have in your code are very different.

The first problem is that you're initializing and populating your `Map` in the body of the class without a statement.
You can either have a static `Map` and a `static {//TODO manipulate Map}` statement in the body of the class, or initialize and populate the Map in a method or in the class' constructor.

The second problem is that you cannot treat a `Map` syntactically like an `array`, so the statement `data["John"] = "Taxi Driver";` should be replaced by `data.put("John", "Taxi Driver")`. 
If you already have a "John" key in your `HashMap`, its value will be replaced with "Taxi Driver".

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("EmpID", EmpID);
map.put("UnChecked", "1");
```